# Correct way to assert that mock expectations have passed

Tags: laravel

When writing tests and using Mockery to spy on classes, is there a correct way to assert that an expectation has passed?

I have this solution at the moment which is obviously wrong, but is there a right way?

```
public function test_page_view_report(): void
{
    $analyticsClient = Mockery::spy(TestAnalyticsClient::class)->makePartial();
    $this->app->instance(AnalyticsClient::class, $analyticsClient);

    $report = new PageViewReport;
    $report->generate();

    try{
        $analyticsClient->shouldHaveReceived('withMetrics')->with([AnalyticsMetric::PAGE_VIEWS])->once();
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

does your test class extends Laravel's TestCase?

If no, then you need to manually call Mockery::close(). Add this at the end of your test class:

```
public function tearDown() {
    \Mockery::close();
}
```